# ASP.NET MVC: Data Annonations and Validation Summary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Model with a couple of properties and I implemented Darin's answer from my previous question: [ASP.NET MVC: Custom Validation by DataAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-data-annonation). This enabled me to validate 4 properties at once (because I needed them together not to exceed a certain length).

The problem is, when I Annonate only 1 of the 4 properties with this custom validator, only that textbox's backgroundcolor will turn red when validation failed. When I annonate all 4 properties all 4 textboxes will turn red, but the error message will be displayed 4 times. Which is ugly. So I set @Html.ValidationSummary(false) so the error messages go in the summary, but all 4 error messages will be summarized (which is logical).

How can I make sure the error message will be displayed only once, while having all 4 textboxes turn red?

Thanks in advance for helping this MVC noob. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but I think the solution might be to pass a list of "Members" to the `ValidationResult` on the `IsValid` overriden method :

[I took the example of your former [question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100300/asp-net-mvc-custom-validation-by-data-annonation)

```
public class CombinedMinLengthAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    public CombinedMinLengthAttribute(int minLength, params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        this.PropertyNames = propertyNames;
        this.MinLength = minLength;
    }

    public string[] PropertyNames { get; private set; }
    public int MinLength { get; private set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var properties = this.PropertyNames.Select(validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty);
        var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null)).OfType<string>();
        var totalLength = values.Sum(x => x.Length) + Convert.ToString(value).Length;
        if (totalLength < this.MinLength)
        {
            List<string> props = this.PropertyNames.ToList();
            props.Add(validationContext.MemberName);
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), props);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tested it for you. 1st of all, I had to edit your code a bit for it to work (which is peer reviewed at the moment). 2nd of all, doesn't work unfortunatly. If I use the Data Annonation on 1 property I only see the errormessage once (and also 1 textbox red which is the problem) and if I annonate all 4 properties I see the errormessage 4 times (which is also not wanted). So basically, no changes. Same result.

Comment: I fixed the code. And I also tested and it does not work 'for MVC' (see my other answer)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `ValidationResult.MemberNames` has not been implement for MVC, see [this](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

> In some situations, you might be tempted to use the second constructor
>   overload of ValidationResult that takes in an IEnumerable of
>   member names. For example, you may decide that you want to display the
>   error message on both fields being compared, so you change the code to
>   this:
>
> ```
> return new ValidationResult(
>     FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new[] { validationContext.MemberName, OtherProperty });
> ```
>
> If you run your code, you will find absolutely no difference. This is
>   because although this overload is present and presumably used
>   elsewhere in the .NET framework, the MVC framework completely ignores
>   ValidationResult.MemberNames.

Comment: but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573232/assign-validationresult-to-specific-field) says it just works..

Comment: In that answer they use IValidatableObject http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx on the model which is not the same as implementing a custom ValidationAttribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx

Comment: Thanks for researching it. So, no solution yet. I'm going a different route, so my real world problem is solved. But could be interesting to see if this can be done in MVC.