# Show ValidationResult errors in-line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a similar question to  [Assign ValidationResult to specific field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573232/assign-validationresult-to-specific-field)

My view-model looks like this:

```
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Password length Should be less than 3")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password is required")]
    [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password length should be less than 3")]       
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }


public static ValidationResult ExtendedValidation(ManageUserViewModel t)
        {
            if (t.Password == t.ConfirmPassword)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                return new ValidationResult("Your passwords must match", new[] { "ConfirmPassword" });
        }
```

My view looks like this:

```
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "The user details were not saved, please see the validation results below")
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
    {

       <div class="formField">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="formField">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
```

But my custom validation error displays at the top of the page, when I want it displayed in-line.

EG, a length check error results in an in-line display, I would like my confirm to do same.

Thanks,
dave

Comment: Did you include the jQuery validation files?

Comment: No, not for this test. I am specifically testing server side validation and plan to add the client side in later.

Comment: Oh I see.  Hmm, I would think using the `ValidationMessageFor` helper would be all it would take.

Answer (score 5):

There's a validation attribute that does exactly what you're trying to achieve with your custom validation. Try adding the `Compare` attribute:

```
[DisplayName("Password")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
[StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Password length should be less than 3")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Your passwords must match")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password is required")]
[StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password length should be less than 3")]       
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

### Additionally...

Sometime I want to add other errors which I want to display using `Html.ValidationMessage()`.  Errors are added to the `ModelState` during server-side validation.  The key matches the id of the control being validated, but you can add your own keys in too.

You could use:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmPassword", "You've done something wrong...");
```

To add an error to the `ConfirmPassword` property, which will then display with you're validation errors for `ConfirmPassword`.  Or you can use a different key:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("MyError", "You've done something wrong...");
```

Then you can display that error in your view using:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("MyError");
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks.  I have upvoted because it's a great suggestion. I would also like to find out how to display errors in-line for other complex validation scenarios.

Comment: I've added an example of how to programmatically add other errors from your code and display them in your view.  Be sure to check out custom validation attributes too.