# ASP.Net MVC : ValidationResult does not accept int.tostring() for member name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

code taken from http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1083/aspnet-mvc-self-validation-model-objects

```
public class Person : IValidatableObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Income { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var pIncome = new[] { "Income" };
            if (Income < 0)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Income cannot be negative", pIncome);
            }
            var pName = new[] { "Name" };
            if (Name.Length > 40)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Name cannot be such huge in length", pName);
            }
            var pBDate = new[] { "BirthDate" };
            if (BirthDate > DateTime.Now)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Sorry Future Date cannot be accepted.", pBDate);
            }

        }
    }
```

### see this line

```
yield return new ValidationResult("Income cannot be negative", pIncome);
```

if i write it like

```
yield return new ValidationResult("Income cannot be negative", Income.ToString());
```

then getting error but the moment we pass a string variable then no problem. so if i need to validate many int type property then do i need to put those property name in

```
string array like  var pIncome = new[] { "Income" }; ?
```

if some many element name is there in array then how to refer it for 2nd argument for `ValidationResult ctor` ?

please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong it is supposed to be collection (IEnumerable) , so it has to be of [] type. changing to .tostring() will not yield array.

```
public ValidationResult(string errorMessage, IEnumerable<string> memberNames);
```

Moreover the overloaded ctor is assign the validation error for one or more fields in the model and if you want to omit passing member name, i guess the error wont be associated with any field rather for the form. please refer another nice answer here [Assign ValidationResult to specific field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573232/assign-validationresult-to-specific-field)