# ASPNET CustomValidation on List of Editor Templates, add input-validation-error css class on nested fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I get my editor template field to apply .input-validation-error css class for custom validation on a collection field property?

Normally I'd add a decorator directly on the view model property but in this case, the validation attribute is on the parent view model for the collection.

I tried to apply the answer similar to what was given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573879/181473

Here is an example with custom validation attribute on the collection property:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Quantities = new List<Quantity>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(ParentViewModel), "ValidateQuantities")]
    public List<Quantity> Quantities { get; set; }

    public static ValidationResult ValidateQuantities(List<Quantity> quantities , ValidationContext context)
    {
        ValidationResult result = null;

        ParentViewModel vm = (ParentViewModel)context.ObjectInstance;

        if (quantities.Sum(m => m.Amount) != 21)
        {
            var memberNames = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < quantities.Count; i++)
            {
                string memberName = context.MemberName + "[" + i.ToString() + "]." + nameof(Quantity.Amount);
                memberNames.Add(memberName);
            }

            // Not working, adding member name to result does not work:
            result = new ValidationResult("Amounts must add up to 21.", memberNames);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Quantity
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new ParentViewModel();

        viewModel.Quantities = new List<Quantity>()
        {
            new Quantity(){ Id = 1000 },
            new Quantity(){ Id = 1001 },
            new Quantity(){ Id = 1002 },
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ParentViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(viewModel);

        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.Quantities.Count; i++)
        {
            string prefix = nameof(viewModel.Quantities) + "[" + i.ToString() + "]";
            TryValidateModel(viewModel.Quantities[i], prefix);
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

This is the Form razor template:

```
@* Views/Form/Index.cshtml *@
@model Mvc5App.Controllers.ParentViewModel

<style>
    .input-validation-error {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
<br>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Form", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
    <br>

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Quantities.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantities[i], "Form/EditorTemplates/Quantity");
        <br>
    }

    <button type="submit" name="SubmitAction" value="SubmitAction" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

And this is the editor template:

```
@* Views/Form/EditorTemplates/Quantity.cshtml *@
@model Mvc5App.Controllers.Quantity

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
```

---

When I call `TryValidateModel(viewModel);` in the POST route the "ParentViewModel.Title" field gets the class applied that changes the background color to red.

But all the "ParentViewModel.Quantities" Amount fields don't get the .input-validation-error css class which I guess means ModelState isn't aware that these fields have an issue.

How can I get all the amount fields to turn red if that custom validation result fails validation?

Comment: well the simple way if you only have one view is that the mvc use jquery validation plugin you can initialize that directly to your client side from script side https://jqueryvalidation.org/ is the site you got advance option and full control over the validation through this and its a way around i had to use in these kind situatns

Comment: @RAHUL S R, I can only use server-side validation in my case.

Comment: why that ? server validation will also do the same thing. it will use the same jquery plugin for client side validations

Comment: @RAHUL S R, My app has javascript disabled for security reasons.

Comment: @RAHULSR, You cannot use jquery.validate in this case, and in any case, client side validation is just a nice bonus - you must always validate on the server.

Comment: Your applying a `ValidationAttribute` to your collection property which means a validation error is applied that property, not to a property of an item within the collection. You have not shown the full code for the attribute (and what you have shown does not make sense). What are you wanting to achieve from this - i.e. what is the expected result?

Comment: Hi @Stephen Muecke, The code is a simplified example of what I'm working on. Intended only to show the behavior of the `CustomValidation` attribute. Based on your comment, it sounds like I should be able to check for an error on the collection property and then update the ModelState for items within based on that validation result. I guess the trick would be to know which validation result was returned for the collection so I know which item properties to apply model state errors. I may have to have several custom validations like the one decorated on the same collection prop.

Comment: There is too much in your code that is not making sense. The purpose of creating a `ValidationAttribute` is to make a reusable piece of code but you have made it specific to only one property. You may as well just use `if (viewModel.Phones.Count > 2) { ModelState.AddModelError("Phones", "Please add only 2 phones max"); }` in your POST method.

Comment: Then there is the fact you passing 3 `Phone` objects to the view so you will always get 3 back (so why are you passing 3 if you only want 2?). Even you `EditorFor()` is incorrect. The `EditorTempate` needs to be in the `/Views/EditorTemplates` folder and be named `Phone.cshtml` (t match the class name), and in the view its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Phones)` which generates the correct html for each item in the collection.